# HttpServletRequest is null when using filter for JWT, headers work on postman but not localhost

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot, filter, jwt, bcrypt

I am using React for front-end and Java spring boot for backend. My api was working before I used Bcrypt to encode passwords but now there seems to be a problem with the internal filter before every api call where the response is null...

this is my WebSecurityConfig.java

```
@EnableWebSecurity
    public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
        @Autowired
        private UserDetailsService myUserDetailsService;
        @Autowired
        private JwtRequestFilter jwtRequestFilter;

        @Autowired
        public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
            auth.userDetailsService(myUserDetailsService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncode());
        }

        @Bean
        public PasswordEncoder passwordEncode(){
            return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
        }

        @Override
        @Bean
        public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
            return super.authenticationManagerBean();
        }

        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
            httpSecurity.csrf().disable()
                    .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/authenticate").permitAll()
                    .antMatchers("/personInfo").permitAll()
                    .antMatchers("/signup").permitAll().
                            anyRequest().authenticated().and().
            addFilterBefore(jwtRequestFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class).exceptionHandling();

        }

    }
```

and this is my JWTRequestFilter.java

I was thinking it may have to do with the passwordEncoder() because my calls were working when i didn't use BcryptPasswordEncoder()...

```
@Component
public class JwtRequestFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    @Autowired
    private MyUserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    private JwtUtil jwtUtil;

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain chain)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

        if(request == null){
            System.out.println("request is null");
        }

        final String authorizationHeader = request.getHeader("Authorization");

        String username = null;
        String jwt = null;

        if (authorizationHeader != null && authorizationHeader.startsWith("Bearer ")) {
            jwt = authorizationHeader.substring(7);
            username = jwtUtil.extractUsername(jwt);
        }

        if (username != null && SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication() == null) {

            UserDetails userDetails = this.userDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(username);

            if (jwtUtil.validateToken(jwt, userDetails)) {

                UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                        userDetails, null, userDetails.getAuthorities());
                usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken
                        .setDetails(new WebAuthenticationDetailsSource().buildDetails(request));
                SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken);
            }
        }
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }

}
```

i am using react for the front-end and am calling with axios

```
async totals(){
        console.log('Bearer ', localStorage.getItem('id_token'));
        let data = await axios.get("http://localhost:8080/totals", {
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + localStorage.getItem('id_token')
            }
        })
            .then(this._checkStatus);

        return data.request.response;
    }
```

the api works when i use the token in postman and so the problem is between the initial request and the filter...

the error I get is -
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8080/totals' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status.

thanks for your time :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If anybody ever gets the same problem, I solved it by adding this line at the end of my configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) method in WebSecurityConfig.java

httpSecurity.cors();

:)